# Xamarin Android, How to add Canvas view to capture user sign

Tags: xamarin.android

Working on xamaring for android in Visual studio, I can see there is no CanvasView.

There are objects like Paint, Canvas, but how to implement theme into a view ?

I need to present white board where the user can sign by hand.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an open source library called [Xamarin Signature Pad](https://github.com/xamarin/SignaturePad). You could use that or look at the source to see how to implement this on your own.